Recursively defined collection fields are omitted in superclass generated api doc
Recursively defined collection fields are omitted in superclass generated api doc.
i think similar to this issue 'https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1158'.
Here is my code.
@Data
public class RecursiveDTO {
    private String testStr;
    private Map<String, List<RecursiveDTO>> children;
}// end of RecursiveDTO.java

@Data
public class AAADTO extends RecursiveDTO {
    private String AA;
    private String BB;
}// end of AAADTO.java

and Controller.java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class TestController {
    @PostMapping(path = "/id", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Operation(summary = "Recursive", description = "SuperClass recursive test")
    public AAADTO testMethod(String aaa) {
        return null;
    }// end of method getApis()
}// end of TestController.java

I can not see the children field in generated api docs.
"schemas": {
  "AAADTO": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "testStr": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "children": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/RecursiveDTO"
          }
        }
      },
      "bb": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "aa": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  },
  "RecursiveDTO": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "testStr": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}

@JsonBackReference annotation isn't solved my problem.
what can i do??
enter image description here
